# How to use Django-simple-captcha on the admin login page?

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-authentication

I would like to add captcha on my django login form using Django Simple Captcha found here: http://code.google.com/p/django-simple-captcha/

This works great if you create a new form but I'm using the django.contrib.auth.forms the one that comes with django. Any idea how I might be able to implement captcha with the existing django auth views or any ways? Thank you!
Please do not suggest using Google reCaptcha.

My urls.py

```
from  django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
urlpatterns = [
      path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='login.html'), name='login') 
      ,...
]
```

---

My login.html

```
<form  class="fadeIn second"  method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

{{ form.as_p }}

<button   type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Login </button>

</form>
```

---

My Forms.py

```
from captcha.fields import CaptchaField

class MyFormCaptcha(forms.Form):
    captcha = CaptchaField()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WL13PtrBTJE)  and [this GitHub project](https://github.com/sunilyadav-web/Django-Captcha) solved my problem. You can customize the project code according to your needs. For me it is as follows.

My urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
  ...
    path('captcha/',include('captcha.urls')),
    path('submit',submit,name='submit')
]
```

My forms.py

```
from captcha.fields import CaptchaField

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    captcha=CaptchaField()
```

My login.html

```
<form action="/submit" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div>
        <label for="fullname">Full Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname">
        </div>
        <br>
     <div>
         <label for="email">Email</label>
         <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
     </div> <br>
        {{form.captcha}}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

My views.py [How to log a user in?](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in)

```
  from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login    
  def test(request):
       form=MyForm()

       return render(request,'captcha/home.html',{'form':form})

def submit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form=MyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name=request.POST['fullname']
            email=request.POST['email']
            print('success')
            print(name)
            print(email)
            user = authenticate(request,username=username,password=password)
       if user is not None:
           login(request, user)
           return redirect('/homepage')   # Redirect to a success page.
       
       else:
           # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
            print('fail')
            messages.success(  request,f 'login failed! username or passwoed is wrong!'
            return redirect('login')
```